# How to use url_helpers in rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to build some links for my datatable and been struggling with it for the past 4 hours.

This is my current code:

```
class UsersDatatable < TemplateDatatable
  def data
    users.map do |user|
      [
        user.id,
        user.nome,
        user.email,
        user.provider.camelize,
        links(user)
      ]
    end
  end

  def links(user)
    html = link_to url_helpers.edit_user_registration_path(user), class: "btn btn-mini btn-info", "data-rel" => "tooltip", title: "Editar", "data-placement" => "top" do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "icon-edit")
    end.html_safe
  end
end

class TemplateDatatable
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
  include ActionView::Context

  delegate :params, to: :@view
  delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'
end
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

```
ArgumentError (arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation)
```

Every thing I try to build my link from my model, doesn't work. I ran through rails issues on github and couldn't find nothing about this.

Any help?

edit:

I also tried the first solution proposed and still it doesn't work. I get the same error. This is what I did:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def edit_registration_path
    edit_user_registration_path(self)
  end
end

def links(user)
  html = link_to user.edit_registration_path, class: "btn btn-mini btn-info", "data-rel" => "tooltip", title: "Editar", "data-placement" => "top" do
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "icon-edit")
end.html_safe
```

This is not a simple thing where you add the url inside a model and call it. This is different than the said duplication.

Comment: it is not. In rails 4.1 every thing works. Something changed in 4.2 and there is no documentation, no help and nothing about this error. I tried a lot of different things and solutions already. I always get the same url_for error.

Comment: Every solution you paste from stackoverflow, I already tried. I still get the same error.

Comment: What you've pasted is a comment saying to comment out the include of UrlHelper. If you read the question, you will see that I don't include it anywhere. Before pasting random solutions, please read the entire question.

Comment: You downvote a question without reading it, I was polite for the whole time and was pointing out that you didn't even read the question before saying it was a duplicate and now you imply you have an asnwer that I bet you don't have. If you are done, please go bother someone else. I'm really trying to get help from who understand things.

Comment: Are you getting the same ArgumentError even after using the updated code?

Comment: What do your routes look like? `rake routes | grep user`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this in you class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def base_uri
    user_path(self)
  end
end

User.find(1).base_uri # => "/users/1"
```

> [Check for refference:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html)

Comment: I updated my question. I tried this already and didn't work as well.

Comment: This is the answer. It is exactly what you need to get the URL helpers into a model. I use it is several apps on Rails 3 and Rails 4 (4.0.1, 4.1.2, and 4.2.3)